# I need the Last Record from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table like followed by

```
ID Cust_ID Amount
1   1       10
2   1       20
3   2       30
4   2       40
5   3       50
```

and I need the latest record of **Cust_Id** result like followed by

```
ID  Cust_Id Amount
2    1       20
4    2       40
5    3       50
```

And I tried the Query like this

```
Select Top 1 *Id,Cust_Id,Amount from tablename
Group by Cust_Id
Order by Id desc
```

Comment: Of course you did your research, please share your attempt and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by cust_id order id desc) rn from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from     
(
select *,
row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by Amount desc) rn   
from tabl
) t where rn=1
```

or use corelate subquery

```
 select t1.* from table t1
  where t1.Amount= (select max(Amount) from table t2 
                     where t1.cust_id=t2.cust_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like following

```
select id,cust_id,amount
from YourTable t1
where id =(select max(t2.id) from YourTable  t2 where t2.Cust_ID=t1.Cust_ID)
order by id
```